# CFDIV, and CFFORM not working right inside a CFWINDOW

Tags: coldfusion, cfform

Hey guys I am having an issue when I'm trying to display a cfdiv inside a cfwindow. It just doesn't show up. No errors, nothing to tell me I'm doing something wrong. The div works just fine if I display it in the page outside of the cfwindow. The cfdiv binds to a page that displays notes. If I try to do a cfinclude with the page the cfdiv binds to I get an error saying that the template can't be found, or there needs to be a mapping. I also have a cftext area inside a cfform and I'm trying to do richtext with it, however it doesn't work either inside of the cfwindow. Is cfwindow incapable of doing this, or is there a trick I don't know about. If you need any other information I'll be happy to provide it.

```
<cfdiv bind="url:/admin/notes/noteDiv.cfm?noteCategory=businessListing#url.listingID#" id="noteDiv">
```

Answer (score 1):

On the page with the cfdiv you need to add:

```
<cfajaximport tags="cfform">
```

That will load up the required Javascript scripts to make cfform work within a window.

Comment: I do have cfajax import on the main page. I thought that would resolve the issue but it doesn't. And normally it will error out if you don't have cfajax import and the page needs it.

Comment: I have an example working fine in ColdFusion 9.  What version of CF are you running?

Comment: CF 8, I have another part of my site where I"m doing something similar but there is no difference in the code, just changed a few url variables.

Answer (score 1):

fully qualify your path and it will work. I just ran into this issue. I have a cfdiv inside a cfwindow

```
<cfdiv
id="idGoesHere"
name="nameGoesHEre"
style="height:300px;width:300px;display:none"
bind="url:http://serverName.att.com/folder/NotesTab_Ajax.cfm?Note_Tag_Type_Code={Tag_Note_Type@change}&case=buildAvailableTagList"
bindOnLoad="false"
/>
```

for some reason stepping the URL back a directory worked too ../folder/NotesTab_Ajax etc

Answer (score 0):

Might need to pull in cfdiv from that cfAjaxProxy call as well.